# Function with Aff callback in FFI

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ffi, purescript

I'm trying to wrap a Javascript library where I have a method `A.bar(f)` which takes as parameter a function `f : B -> void`.

Since I'd like to use `bar` to perform some anynchronous computations, on the Purescript side, I have a function declaration

```
foreign import foo :: Fn2 A (B -> Aff Unit) -> EffectFnAff Unit
```

In its corresponding Javascript file, I have something like

```
exports.foo = function (a, f) {
  return function (onError, onSuccess) {
    a.bar(function (b) {
      f(b)
    })

    return function (cancelError, cancelerError, cancelerSuccess) {
      cancelerSuccess()
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I have is that `f(b)` is an `Aff` object and I don't know how to execute it on the Javascript side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing PureScript data structures from FFI-ied JavaScript is always a bad idea. You're relying not only on the specific way the library is written (without compiler support to catch errors!), but also on the compiler itself, for the runtime representation may change from one compiler version to another (note that this doesn't apply to `EffectFnAff`, because it's explicitly intended for FFI and carefully defined as such, [in terms of `EffectFn2`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/5.1.2/docs/Effect.Aff.Compat#t:EffectFnAff)).

The way to represent an effectful computation in FFI is via `Effect`:

```
foreign import foo :: Fn2 A (B -> Effect Unit) -> EffectFnAff Unit
```

Such function can now be called from JavaScript the way you do it - as `f(b)`.

And if you want the consumer of your library to provide `Aff`, what you do is make a wrapper:

```
foreign import foo_ :: Fn2 A (B -> Effect Unit) (EffectFnAff Unit)

foo :: A -> (B -> Aff Unit) -> Aff Unit
foo a f = fromEffectFnAff $ runFn2 foo_ a (launchAff_ <<< f)
```

Then you just export the wrapper `foo`, but not the FFI import `foo_`.

---

On a somewhat related note, I would also recommend doing away with `EffectFnAff`, because you're not actually launching anything asynchronous, but are always calling `cancelerSuccess()`.

So instead, I would recommend this:

```
// JavaScript
exports.foo = (a, f) => a.bar(f)

-- PureScript
foreign import foo_ :: EffectFn2 A (B -> Effect Unit) Unit

foo :: A -> (B -> Aff Unit) -> Aff Unit
foo a f = liftEffect $ runEffectFn2 foo_ a (launchAff_ <<< f)
```

The wrapper still has `Aff` in both plces - this is assuming that you need the whole thing to fit into `Aff` for your own reasons. Otherwise it could be just `foo = runEffectFn2 foo_`

Comment: thanks! In the end I guess that using `Effect` for the foreign function is the best option

Comment: @Fyodor Shouldn't `foo_` be defined as `EffectFn2 A (B -> Effect Unit) Unit` when on the js side there is just an uncurried function which does unwrapped effectful `a.bar` call?

Comment: @paluh yes, you're absolutely right. That was an oversight. Fixed now.